# How much of Doctor Strange is origin story?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange

Can anyone tell me what percentage of the new (2016) *Doctor Strange* movie is devoted to detailing his origins? Or, can this film as a whole be considered an origin story?

Believe it or not finding out this answer is harder than it sounds without also being exposed to spoilers and impossible without being exposed to (unwanted) reviewers opinions. I just want a neutral answer.

As for what constitutes origin story being opinion: I'd say if the movie starts with the viewer having to accept he has powers somehow and no more than 15% of time is spent on short flashbacks that hint at his origins: that is **not** an origin story for the purposes of this question.  Anything more that that about origins is.

Comment: A point that I rarely see discussed is that (in my opinion) the reason the whole film feels like origin story is because not only do they have to set up Doctor Strange, they also have to set up the entire Mystic side of the MCU.

Comment: @SGR Thanks for the input, but I don't read blogs or forums on comic book movies, and I'm not trying to kick off any discussion. I really like the Doctor Strange character but I can't stomach another origin story, personally

Comment: It's an excellent story on its own merit- I think it's worth the risk. Just because we see someone grow into a character, doesn't mean it's just 'another origin story'... although it likely is considered to be.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a highly opinionated question because people will feel different about what is considered "end of origin story".

I argue the whole movie is an origin story.

It starts in the beginning of him being a surgeon, loosing his ability to operate, searching for solutions, the whole "superhero in training montage", climax where he finds out his true purpose and powers and ending in him being what is considered to be *The* Doctor Strange everybody knows.

There is no *cut* in the movie where you could say: "Okay, NOW origin is over" because (again, highly opinionated), only at the end of the movie is the character fully developed and whole.

Anything in between is just a half truth.